# What's the difference between "Receive Data" and "Receive Response" in chrome timeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the [offical doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/performance-reference),it says that:

> Receive Data:   Data for a request was received. There will be one or more Receive Data events.
>
> Receive Response:   The initial HTTP response from a request.

But I am not very clear about what it means.I think the The "Receive Response" is clear because we know that a http request has the responese body.But what does the "Receive Data" mean?And why maybe there will be more than one Receive Data events?

Could anyone explain it?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Data can be received due to HTTP2's push feature to send data down, other JS events grabbing stuff, Service Workers doing their thing (which falls under other JS too), etc. There are numerous reasons data can be received from remote resources and that is what `Receive Data` indicates.

Initial Response will fire once as the initial server response is received for each request made. So each resource should have that ticked somewhere on the timeline. If the response doesn't fit into that initial response completely, then you'll see Data Received events as extra packets come through to finish off a request completely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.BTW,you say these data are from remote resources,but why I can't see them in the network panel? @Garbee

Comment: You'd need to provide a link to a site where you're seeing that problem for analysis. They should show up after being requested by the page.

Comment: [simple test](http://www.blog.ne-smalltown.com/W3C_Test/script_tag_test.html).

I upload a simple test, and above is the site.Now I think the "Receive Data" is just part of the "Receive Response" details.The "Receive Response"  is just shows the HTTP connection is successful to establish(We know it's based on TCP/IP),in other words,the server receive the connection request and response it,and the response arrived client successfully. @Garbee

Comment: And the the real "Receive Response" is divided many piece and is passed by many times and that's what "Receive Data" mean and why there is more than one "Receive Data" generally .If I am wrong,please let me know.

In addition,I find that the print order in the console is't constant,could you tell me some principle of this?Thanks a lot. @Garbee

Comment: So I was off in the way the initial response was worded. It fires once for *every* response. Data received is for each subsequent chunk of that request coming down. In your case, things are small enough the initial response is pretty much all there is. So you aren't seeing multiple data received events for the full data on larger items. On the note of the console stuff, that is because the scripts are async, therefore they are pulled without blocking but execute immediately once received. Check the network waterfall and you'll understand why the second is firing before the first.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Garbee